# If Int is a negative value, is there a way to express it as 0?

Tags: swift

I faced situation, which is

```swift
let IntA = IntB - IntC
let usingInt = IntA <= 0 ? 0 : IntA
```

But, Just not smart I felt. 
Is there some cool methods??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `max` function for this:

```
let IntA = IntB - IntC
let usingInt = max(IntA, 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using the setter methods to do the same thing suggested in the other answer?

```
var result: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        result = max(0, result)
    }
}
```

Use this variable to store your calculation result.

```
result = 4 - 5
print(result) //0
```

Comment: @KazukiSugita you are better off using the `max` function like it's mentioned in the other answer if you are going to use it only once.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri not necessarily `didSet { result = max(0,result) }`

Comment: @LeoDabus Wouldn’t that cause recursion?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri nope

Comment: @LeoDabus oh... i did not even give that a second thought because i was under the impression it would cause recursion. Thanks. (Y)